# Where to add code which filters results returned from Spring service

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

In my Spring controller I am receiving a List of items from a service 
and then using custom code within the controller to create a new filtered List
which is a subset of the List retured from the service.

I don't think this filtering code should take place in the controller ?

Here is my controller :

```
    @Controller
    public class MyController {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

        @RenderMapping
        public String getValues(ModelMap modelMap){

            List<String> = myService.getNewValues();


            List<String> filteredList = ......
            /**
                Code here to process the List and convert it to
                specific List
            */
            modelMap.addAttribute("values", filteredList);
        }
}
```

Should the filtering take place at the service implementation layer ?

So instead of `myService.getNewValues();` I should use a new method which filters the results : `myService.getNewFilteredValues();` ?

Note : the method `myService.getNewFilteredValues()` will be a new method and will contain same code as filtering code specified in `MyController`

Comment: Can myService.getNewFilteredValues() do it more efficiently than MyController?

Comment: @Andre ive clarified the question : "the method myService.getNewFilteredValues() will be a new method and will contain same code as filtering code specified in controller" so will be just as effecient as MyController implementation

Comment: Is myService.getNewValues() called from anywhere else?

Comment: @Andre nope, its just called from MyController

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would expose `myService.getValues();` and let the service hide the filtering and other logic from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

If the filtering is part of buisness logic I would place it on service level. Add a method to Service `getFilteredValues()` which in tunr calls the `getValues()`

UPD: If it's controller specific logic (some technical filtering e.g. to reduce amount of transferred data) then leave it on Controller's level.